# why am I getting weird error on concatenation by using angular sass?

Tags: css, angular, sass, scss-mixins

**how can I solve this problem in the main project because I used this code in all files but before a month I didn't have any issue but after sometime vocode shows me this error**

[here is the image that shows the error of ) expected scss(css-rparentexpected) and this error is throwing error on vscode problems tab in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptrfN.png)

*this is the second image*

[this is the pic in that I am facing issues on working our main project and vs code throwing error but there is no issue when I compile it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeaIE.png)

```css
// ----Media query mixin-----------//
@mixin min-mq($min-screen-size) {
  @media (min-width: $min-screen-size + "px") {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin max-mq($max-screen-size) {
  @media (max-width: $max-screen-size +"px") {
    @content;
  }
}

// ----------------------------For Orientation-----------------------//
@mixin landscape-orientation($max-screen-size, $orientation) {
  @media (max-width: $max-screen-size +"px") and (orientation: $orientation) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin btw-mq($min-screen-size, $max-screen-size, $pixel-ratio, $orientation) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: $min-screen-size +"px") and (max-width: $max-screen-size +"px") and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: $pixel-ratio) and (orientation: $orientation) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin btw-sz($min-screen-size, $max-screen-size) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: $min-screen-size +"px") and (max-width: $max-screen-size +"px") {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the error, you're facing not just a screenshot of the red bar.

Comment: I just updated this code and you can see my code, the first link has a error image if you click on this then you will be navigated to image. I didn't use stack overflow before..